# SUM de uma tabela menos o SUM de outra no mesmo campo

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Olá, sou autodidata e já faço algumas consultas em *SQL* mas "emperrei" nesta.

Preciso de uma lista em que um dos campos deve mostrar o total de uma coluna, menos o total de outra que está em uma segunda tabela.

Exemplo:

**Tabela A (Facturas)**

```
+------+---------+------------+------------+
| id   | docnum  |   valor    | clienteid  |
+------+---------+------------+------------+
  1        25        150,00       23
  2        26        300,00       22
  3        27        450,25       23
  3        28        600,00       23
```

**Tabela B (Recibos)**

```
+------+---------+------------------+-----------------------+--------+
| id   | docnum  | numfac | valor   | valorpago| clienteid  | Tipo   |
+------+---------+------------------+-----------------------+--------+
   1       1         25     150,00      150,00       23        REC 
   2       2         27     450,25      100,00       23        REC
   3      25         45     -25,00      -25,00       23        FAL 
   4       3         27     450,25      100,00       23        REC
   5      88         78      55,25      -55,25       23        FAL
```

> A Tabela *A* contém as Facturas emitidas
>
> A Tabela *B* Contem OS Valores Pagos

Eu preciso obter uma listagem com as facturas que faltam pagar tendo os pagamentos parciais e ignorar as que já estão pagas.

O resultado deveria ser o seguinte:

```
Cliente ValorDocumento ValorEmDebito
   22       300,00        300,00
   23      1000,25        800,25
```

se utilizar esta query:

```
SELECT f.docnum AS Doc,
       f.clienteid AS Cliente,
       f.valor AS ValorDocumento,
       f.valor - SUM(COALESCE(r.valorpago, 0)) As ValorEmDebito
  FROM Facturas f
  LEFT JOIN Recibos r
    ON r.numfac = f.docnum
WHERE   (r.tipodoc IS NULL or r.tipodoc='rec' ) and f.clientid=23 
 GROUP BY f.docnum,
          f.clienteid,
          f.valor
HAVING f.valor - SUM(COALESCE(r.valorpago, 0)) > 0;
```

que filtra pelo cliente 23
só aparece a fatura paga parcialmente

```
  Cliente ValorDocumento ValorEmDebito
     23      450,25        250,25
```

e queria que aparecesse

```
 Cliente ValorDocumento ValorEmDebito
   23       1000,25         600,25
```

Comment: Qual o `SGBD` utilizado?

Comment: Olá, Estou a Utilizar O TADO Delphi XE7

Comment: Esse não é o `SGBD`. Estou perguntando se você está utilizando `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, `Oracle`...

Comment: Mas cara, você tá fazendo `WHERE` pelo cliente 23... o cliente 23 só tem uma fatura que tá completamente paga e uma parcial, não tem como aparecer a de 300,00 se ela não é do cliente que você especificou no `WHERE`

Comment: E na real como vai aparecer 350,25 se ele pagou 2x 100,00

Comment: Tem Razão, Já Reformulei... é que já ando nisto há dias e o cerebro qualquer dia rescinde contrato

Comment: Ah, você quer por cliente, não por documento. Isso altera completamente a solução

Comment: Pois Foi Erro Meu ... peço imensa desculpa pela confusão

Answer (score 1):

Use a cláusula `HAVING` para filtrar os resultados que deseja (Com o débito restante maior que 0):

```
SELECT f.docnum AS Doc,
       f.clienteid AS Cliente,
       f.valor AS ValorDocumento,
       f.valor - SUM(COALESCE(r.valorpago, 0)) As ValorEmDebito
  FROM Facturas f
  LEFT JOIN Recibos r
    ON r.numfac = f.docnum
 GROUP BY f.docnum,
          f.clienteid,
          f.valor
HAVING f.valor - SUM(COALESCE(r.valorpago, 0)) > 0;
```

A `query` acima resultará em:

```
| Doc | Cliente | ValorDocumento | ValorEmDebito |
| --- | ------- | -------------- | ------------- |
| 26  | 22      | 300            | 300           |
| 27  | 23      | 450.25         | 250.25        |
```

- Na `query` as duas tabelas são vinculadas por meio de um `LEFT JOIN` pois pode haver algum documento sem nenhum pagamento e queremos mostrar até mesmo esses casos;
- O `COALESCE` é usado para os casos em que não houver recibo, garantindo que o cálculo do débito funcione corretamente considerando 0 no pagamento;
- A cláusula `HAVING` é utilizada para filtrar os registros considerando apenas os que ainda não possuem pagamento maior ou igual ao valor da fatura;
- A cláusula `HAVING` é utilizada no lugar do `WHERE` porque ela precisa de funções de agregação (neste caso o `SUM`). Ou seja, a restrição só será aplicada depois de agrupados os registros.

> [`COALESCE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Avalia os argumentos na ordem e retorna o valor atual da primeira expressão que não é avaliada como `NULL` inicialmente. Por exemplo, `SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 'third_value', 'fourth_value');` retorna o terceiro valor porque esse é o primeiro valor que não é nulo.

---

> [`HAVING`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Especifica um critério de pesquisa para um grupo ou uma agregação. `HAVING` pode ser usado somente com a instrução `SELECT`. `HAVING` é normalmente usado com uma cláusula `GROUP BY`. Quando `GROUP BY` não for usado, haverá um único grupo agregado e implícito.

---

> [`SUM`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Retorna a soma de todos os valores ou somente os valores `DISTINCT` na expressão. `SUM` pode ser usado exclusivamente com colunas numéricas. Valores nulos são ignorados.

Você pode conferir o resultado no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8o4RpaXSg2ScNEDs6MeEjX/0).

Comment: Obrigado, Talvez Por Ter Ocultado um detalhe que não considerei importante mas talvez seja... a tabela dos recibos também alberga outros registos que não são recibos e por isso no resultado aparecem valores que não deveriam.. na query que exemplificou tentei alterar para  "  ON r.numfac = f.numfac and (r.tipodoc='rec' or r.tipodoc IS NULL)"  mas assim não mostra os documentos não pagos que não constam na tabela dos recibos

Comment: @ONossoTone você pode colocar um `WHERE r.tipodoc IS NULL OR r.tipodoc = 'rec'` na `query`e terá esse filtro a mais

Comment: Obrigado, Tenho a Query Assim:
  SELECT f.TransDocNumber AS Doc,
       f.PartyID AS Cliente,
       f.TotalAmount AS ValorDocumento,
       f.TotalAmount - SUM(COALESCE(r.TotalPayedAmount, 0)) As ValorEmDebito
  FROM SaleTransaction f
  LEFT JOIN AccountTransactionDetails r
    ON r.DocNumber = f.TransDocNumber
 WHERE  (r.TransDocument IS NULL or r.TransDocument='rec' ) and f.partyID=514777435
 GROUP BY f.PartyID
          ,f.TransDocNumber
          ,f.TotalAmount
HAVING f.TotalAmount - SUM(COALESCE(r.TotalPayedAmount, 0)) > 0

Comment: mas Só mostra as Parcialmente pagas 
estarei a fazer algo mal?

Comment: @ONossoTone consegue colocar um exemplo dos registros que você tem nas tabelas pra podermos trabalhar com eles e testar?

Comment: @ONossoTone você disse na pergunta que queria apenas as que estão em aberto. Se você quer as que estou pagas tire o `HAVING`

Comment: Obrigado Sorack, Pois Disse e é isso que quero. mas tenho uma factura que não esta paga e por isso não consta nos recibos mas não aparece na listagem

Comment: @ONossoTone sem acesso aos dados é difícil precisar por que isso acontece

Comment: Obrigado Sorack,  E como posso enviar uma copia da tabela?

Comment: @ONossoTone tenta fazer um DB Fiddle como que eu coloquei na minha resposta reproduzindo o erro que fica mais fácil de te ajudar

Comment: O que eu Pretendia era juntar os valores em debito numa linha  por cada cliente

Comment: @ONossoTone a `query` original já faz isso... Não tem como aparecer um registro com o valor que você informou. Veja o questionamento que fiz no comentário da sua pergunta

Answer (score 0):

A consulta abaixo permite-lhe mostrar os resultados que pretende:

```
SELECT      A.docnum                        AS doc
        ,   A.clienteid                     AS cliente
        ,   A.valor                         AS valordocumento
        ,   A.valor - ISNULL(B.valor, 0)    AS valoremdebito
FROM        tabelaA     A
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT      numfac
                        ,   clienteid
                        ,   SUM(valorpago) AS valorpago
                FROM        tabelaB
                GROUP BY    numfac
                        ,   clienteid
            )           B   ON  B.numfac    = A.numfac
                            AND B.clienteid = A.clienteid
WHERE       (A.valor - ISNULL(B.valor, 0)) > 0
ORDER BY    A.docnum
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Pela Rapida Resposta, Vou Já Por Em pratica

Comment: Atenção que criei o exemplo para funcionar em **SQL Server**. Se estiver a utilizar um outro motor de `SGBD` terei que adaptar.

Comment: Tem razão, não reparei. Resposta editada.

Answer (score 0):

> *Eu preciso obter uma listagem com as facturas que faltam pagar tendo os pagamentos parciais e ignorar as que já estão pagas.*
>
> *O resultado deveria ser o seguinte:*
> Cliente ValorDocumento ValorEmDebito

```
-- código #1
with 
soma_Recibos as (
SELECT numfac, sum (valorpago) as acumPgto
  from Recibos
  where tipodoc = 'REC' 
        or tipodoc is null
  group by numfac
),
Facturas_em_aberto as (
SELECT A.docnum, A.clienteid, A.valor, 
       coalesce (B.acumpgto, 0) as acumpgto
  from Facturas as A
       left join soma_Recibos as B on B.numfac = A.docnum
  where B.numfac is null
        or B.acumPgto < A.valor
)
SELECT clienteid, 
       sum (valor) as ValorDocumento,
       sum (valor - acumpgto) as ValorEmDebito
  from Facturas_em_aberto
  group by clienteid;
```

O código acima considera que a numeração de fatura é independente de cliente, conforme se deduz da amostra de dados da Tabela A.

o código foi construído utilizando CTE - *common table expression* -, que facilita programar, compreender e dar manutenção. Detalhes no artigo “[Programação modular com expressões de tabela (CTE)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/artigos/)”.

Comment: Obrigado José Diniz, Em Principio Resolve o Problema, mas deve ter ainda mais alguns filtros para analisar, este conceito é de facto muito versátil.. vou queimar mais 25 ou 30 neurónios...  Mais Uma Vez Obrigado